# Fuzzy regression discontinuity design in Stata

Tags: stata, instrumental-variables, regression-discontinuity

I am currently running computations through a "Fuzzy" Regression discontinuity Design. Suppose my data are in the following form:

- $Z$: **assignment variable**; if $Z > Z_0$ then the person is assigned to the treatment with a certain probability $p_D$ (since we are in the "fuzzy" RDD framework, $p_D<1$).
- $D$: **treatment status**; $D=1$ if the person is treated, 0 otherwise.
- $X$: set of exogenous variables.
- $Y$: **Binary outcome** variable.

To my knowledge - see e.g. [1] - running a fuzzy RDD is equivalent to apply Instrumental Variables using $Z$ as instrument (hence at the first stage we should have $D$ regressed on $Z$ and $X$).

In order to estimate the model through Stata I used the following code:

```
biprobit (Y = X D) (D = X Z)
```

According to some research I have done - see Nichols' pdf at [2] - the `-biprobit-` package should be required because of the binary nature of the endogenous variable ($D$).

Do you find the above codes correct? Is it also possible to use a simple linear probability model like this?

```
ivregress 2sls Y X (D=Z)
```

Thanks fo any help,

Stefano

> [1] Angrist, J. D., Pischke, J. (2008). *Mostly Harmless Econometrics: An Empiricist's Companion*. Princeton University Press.
>
> [2]: http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://www.stata.com/meeting/chicago11/materials/chi11_nichols.pdf&ei=GvVnUvKOFIPv4gT-moH4DQ&usg=AFQjCNGv9pmEIOIvhVsmmMq38q05pRbFbg&bvm=bv.55123115,d.bGE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is partial answer. I think you should probably use both the `biprobit` and the `ivreg/ivreg2` commands to check how robust your effects are. I like the `biprobit` approach given your data, but it does make some strong assumptions (no heteroskedasticity, no hetrogenous effects, normality of errors).* However, there's also a dedicated RD command in Stata called `rdrobust`. It can handle the fuzzy design and may be installed with:

```
net install rdrobust, from(http://www-personal.umich.edu/~cattaneo/rdrobust) replace
```

You can find an intro to the command in Cattaneo, Calonico, and Titiunik's *Stata Journal* paper [Robust Data-Driven Inference in the Regression-Discontinuity Design](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~cattaneo/papers/Calonico-Cattaneo-Titiunik_2013_STATA.pdf).

---

*Austin Nichols' [simulation results](http://www.stata.com/meeting/chicago11/materials/chi11_nichols.pdf) indicate that the marginal effects may be less sensitive than the latent index function parameters to biprobit assumption violations. The LPM model is also [not always](https://www.google.com/search?q=LPM%20site%3adavegiles.blogspot.com&oq=LPM%20site%3adavegiles.blogspot.com&aqs=chrome..69i57.11781j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) the model of steel that A&P make it out.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I am applying fuzzy RDD on some simulations where, for simplicity, errors are normally distributed and homoschedasticity holds. Still, my DGP is characterized by heterogeneity. I am wondering if it is possible to address it through the the -biprobit- approach.

Comment: In theory, it's problematic since you're dividing $\beta_i$ by $\sigma_i=\sigma$ to get to the standard normal. However, according to Austin, biprobit is remarkably robust to variability in the treatment effect (random coefficients) in simulation.